# Not able to access service using <nodeip>:<nodeport>

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

**I have the following `Services` in `GKE` cluster:**

```sh
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
currency-conversion   NodePort       10.105.13.208   <none>          8100:30285/TCP   5h56m   app=currency-conversion
currency-exchange     LoadBalancer   10.105.6.251    34.72.191.147   8000:31396/TCP   5h59m   app=currency-exchange
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.105.0.1      <none>          443/TCP          3d12h   <none>
```

**I have the following `Nodes` in `GKE`:**

```
NAME                                                STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION         INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP       OS-IMAGE                             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gke-my-first-cluster-1-default-pool-c2c915e7-818c   Ready    <none>   9h    v1.17.6-gke.7   10.128.0.9    35.194.22.175     Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.19.112+        docker://19.3.6
gke-my-first-cluster-1-default-pool-c2c915e7-xg0r   Ready    <none>   9h    v1.17.6-gke.7   10.128.0.8    104.197.190.232   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.19.112+        docker://19.3.6
gke-my-first-cluster-1-default-pool-c2c915e7-z8fn   Ready    <none>   9h    v1.17.6-gke.7   10.128.0.10   35.188.75.231     Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.19.112+        docker://19.3.6
```

When I try to use command below:

- `curl http://35.194.22.175:30285/`

I'm getting the `Timeout error`.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. The `Timeout error` you are experiencing is caused by `VPC Firewall`.  By default it will block the connections made as you've shown. To make it work you can either: 1. Expose your application by service type of `LoadBalancer` (which you already did with other service and connect to it with `curl EXTERNAL_IP:PORT`) 2. Create a rule that will allow network traffic to get to this node on this particular port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access your service `currency-conversion` because of the firewall rules. **Your requests are going to be blocked by default by `VPC Firewall`.**
To allow traffic to your `currency-conversion` service you can either:

- Create a firewall rule that will allow the traffic to enter (you will be able to `$ curl NODE_IP:NODE_PORT)`:

  - `$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow tcp:NODE_PORT`
- Create a service of type `LoadBalancer` which will allocate public IP address and create a forwarding rule for access (you've already done it with `currency-exchange`):

  - `$ kubectl expose deployment NAME --type=LoadBalancer --port=PORT-CONTAINER-IS-LISTENING-ON`

You can read more about Kubernetes services here:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: How to: Exposing apps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps)* - specific to `GKE`
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Concepts: Service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

---

> ### Disclaimer!
>
> `$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow tcp:node-port`
>
> Above rule will allow traffic to **ALL** instances in the default network.

For more secure approach you can use the below rule:

```
$ gcloud compute --project=PROJECT_NAME firewall-rules create allow-nodeport --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:30285,udp:30285 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=gke-gke-XYZ-ABC-node
```

Focusing on parts of above command:

- `--direction=INGRESS` - it's for incoming requests
- `--network=default` - use the name of the network your `GKE` cluster is in
- `--rules=tcp:30285,udp:30285` - use the port number (30285) your service is exposed on
- `--source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0` - this parameter will allow traffic from any IP
- `--target-tags=gke-gke-XYZ-ABC-node` - use the `network tag` of your `GKE` cluster nodes. You can get this `network tag` by going into `GCP -> Compute Engine -> GKE-NODE -> VM Instance details -> network tags`.

You can also take a look here:

- *[Cloud.google.com: VPC: Using firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)*